# (Ended) Livestreaming question answering!

Tags: discussion, community-event, community

Since I answer a lot of questions and they seem to be pretty popular (I'm #1 this month and last year), I will be livestreaming my process of answering some tricky gamingSE questions, starting in 1 hour, which is 14:00 UTC on 2020-02-25. Maybe some people can find interesting tips in it or have some tips for me.

**Update**: After resolving some copyright claims, the stream archive is now public again:

<s>**Update to the update**: There was some new copyright stuff and it's private again. This is getting seriously annoying…</s> (fixed again)

Comment: Are you planning to upload these videos to your youtube channel afterwards? I ask since the idea of "instructional" videos which demonstrates the process behind producing high quality answers seems like something some new users could find helpful (the SE team may too, actually). I don't think the livestream format may be ideal for that, though, which is why I hope you plan to upload them to youtube as "Regular" videos afterwards.

Comment: Yes, stream archive and eventually also highlights video (but I don't have a video editing program set up currently).

Comment: I'm pretty sure nobody watched the stream live, despite the 4 upvotes.  But once I set it to public again, hopefully some people will watch it over time.

Comment: If this stream  happens again will there be a longer announcement period? This stream started and stopped before I even knew it was live

Comment: @FabianRöling stream would've been at ~12am for me, I was sound asleep in bed sorry!

Comment: @PausePause Sure, I can do that. I did it for just an hour this time because I expected stuff to usually move down on the front page somewhat faster. I'm surprised that it's still in "hot meta posts". Also, what time would be more beneficial for people here? I have no idea what timezones most people are in. BTW, the video is currently unlisted instead of public, but I would suggest using an adblocker when watching it, because I currently have no control over whether ads play on it.

Comment: [Based on the 2019 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) the top  four countries that use StackOverflow is USA (23%), India (10%), Germany (6%), UK (6%). For the most views you'd probably want American or European time zones.

Comment: I guess I should fit my stream between ~16:00 UTC (6:00 in Hawaii) and ~22:00 UTC (24:00 in Finland etc.) and announce it at least a day in advance.

Comment: Should I be doing this too? :P

Comment: Sure, it's good to see other perspectives of this as well.

Comment: Now the question is out of "hot meta posts". I guess I should best announce my streams 1 week ahead then.

Comment: I have updated the post, the video will be public again any moment now (currently uploading).

Comment: @FabianRöling just so you know: it's still in Hot Meta Posts. There isn't much competition.

Comment: Now you have a second one to "compete" ;)

Comment: What's with the copyright issues? How much worse than simple playthroughs can insightful discussion be?

Comment: @Joachim I assume the video has copyrighted music playing

Comment: @Wrigglenite No, it does not, but first I got claimed a bunch of times by one company and one time by another, then all claims by the one company got released, but not by the other company, I tried a few things to contact them, but eventually gave up and just removed the track (I had recorded microphone, desktop audio and music separately). But because YouTube for some reason does not allow replacing parts with self uploaded audio files, only their audio library garbage, I had to completely re-upload the edited stream archive. Then I got claimed a bunch of times by the one company again, but …

Comment: … this time they only released about half of all claims when I appealed, so now I had to do the second appeal process and they didn't do anything yet. They have up to 30 days to respond. And if they do it wrong again, I would actually need to sue them. YouTube copyright is a mess.

Comment: And now the video is public again, hopefully it can finally stay that way.

Comment: @FabianRöling You got "claimed by a company"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Joachim a lot of companies (like Universal, Sony etc) have automated systems to detect infringing material, which issue automatic takedown notices - placing the onus on the video creator (i.e. Fabian in this case) to prove that it's not infringing. The automated systems are notoriously overzealous - If you make a video and include say, 10 seconds of a song you like, it could be flagged and your video taken down until you appeal against it.

Comment: Almost. It wasn't a huge movie company, just some company that multiple smaller artists use for (I think) rights management etc. And if you use even just 1 second of a copyrighted track, that is illegal, so that would not be "overzealous". But I don't use any copyrighted music, I have even researched a long time to make sure that that's the case, but some tracks are still claimed every single time, because YouTube's content ID system sucks. And for one track I couldn't even contact the artist, so I uploaded the stream archive again without that track, but that triggered all other claims again.