# Can I ask about how to support black game developers?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Because of current events, I'd like to ask a question (doesn't really matter whether on meta or on the main site) about how to find and support black game developers, or otherwise support the Black Lives Matter movement through buying games, playing games or other gaming related activities. Note that this isn't that question, this is just to gauge whether it would be on-topic for this site.

Comment: On main, probably not. Personally I'd allow it on meta.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a shopping recommendation to me, and I'm not sure if it would be possible to craft this in a way that doesn't fall into shopping recommendation

Comment: Asking how to find and support black game developers seems like a proper question to me: it can be answered with factual information, whereas shopping recommendations are not allowed because they are based on opinion, right?

Comment: I love this thought. Maybe not as a list of games that have developed, but include resources that allow you to find them. Humble Bundle just recently announced 1 million dollars to help black game developers and I think we can do something here to help also.

Comment: I agree with @Unionhawk and think that, by the rules of the site, a question like that would be off-topic.  It might be a better discussion topic for chat.  A question like this reminds me of the [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/691711) post and the discussion [Should the “Time to take a stand” question be closed / moved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342480/691711).  It was a contentious topic.

Comment: To be clear, I believe this is on topic on Meta, and perhaps we should just de-abstract this from "can I ask this on main" to "I am asking this on Meta". I will bring this up to the mod team.

Answer (score 11):

+1 for very important topic.

I think you (and everyone else) can do a lot of different things:

1. On the Main site ask good on-topic questions about games you want to promote. No need to mention how and by whom they were created, good questions will increase game popularity anyway. Extra points for making it into hot network questions. Same goes for answering, upvoting and bounty awarding.
2. This meta is open to all kind gaming related questions and activities. For example, you can promote your streams (like [(Ended) Livestreaming question answering!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14936/ended-livestreaming-question-answering)) or you can run a bounty marathon (like [OMG HOLIDAY BOUNTY GIVEAWAY 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/omg-holiday-bounty-giveaway-2012)) or maybe invent some new type of [community-event](/questions/tagged/community-event).
3. Create a community promotion ad: [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14958/community-promotion-ads-2020) . If I understand conditions correctly, your ad will be shown on the main site if it gets at lest 6 upvotes in that question.

Comment: Community ads! That's perfect, actually.

Comment: I like the idea of a community ad a lot - perhaps something in support of http://www.blackgamedevs.com/ ?